# ASP.NET MVC : completed job should go down (Sorting on Front-End page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

Model

```
public class Jobs
{
    public List<string> JobNames { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    public static List<string> sorteddailyreports= new List<string>();
    static Jobs jobnames;

    public static List<string> dailyreports = new List<string>();
    
    public ActionResult GetJobs()
    {
        jobnames =new Jobs();
        dailyreports = new List<string> { "M2I|0705","FGI|1220","SDI|0100" };
        sorteddailyreports=dailyreports.ToList().OrderBy(x=> x.Split('|')[1].Trim()).ToList();
        jobnames.JobNames = sorteddailyreports;           
        return View(jobnames);
    }

    public static int IsJobRan(string job)
    {
        int completed = 0;

        if (true)  //some condition 
        {
            completed = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            completed = -1;
        }

        return completed;
    }
}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Jobs

<body>
    @foreach(string jobdetails in Model.JobNames)
    {
        string job = jobdetails.Split('|')[0].Trim();
        string runtime = jobdetails.Split('|')[1].Trim();
        string fruntime = runtime.Substring(0, 2) + ":" + runtime.Substring(2, 2);

        if (WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.IsJobRan(jobdetails)==1)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.Label(job)
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @Html.Label(fruntime)
            </tr>
        }
        <br />
    }
</body>
```

I am expecting in `view` if the `method return 1` it means jobs completed then `completed job should go down` and if the method returns other than 1 the `job is sorted on the basis of runtime`.

For example: if `M2I` job runs successfully and returns 1, then the `Output` which I am expecting in view. Completed Job `M2I` should go down and `other jobs` like `SDI and FGI` are sorted on the basis of runtime.

```
SDI 0100
FGI 1220
M2I 0705
```

Code which I am trying but didn't get the desired result

```
sorteddailyreports = dailyreports.ToList()
                                 .OrderBy(x => x.Split('|')[1].Trim())
                                 .ToList();
```

Please amend the code, I am new in Asp.net MVC Thanks in advance.

I am trying Generic Move method for moving the Completed List to last on the Front End page.

Add this `logic in Controller` to move completed list to last index still not able to get sorting on front end. call this method in view still Not sure this Move method is a workable solution for sorting at front end.

```
public static void Move(List<string> list, int newIndex, int oldIndex)
       {
           var item = list[oldIndex];
           list.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
           if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--;
           list.Insert(newIndex, item);
       }
```

Comment: Hi developer, can you please help me on amending the code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi developer community, I have edited the code, just add hardcoded dailyreports value in the controller.

Comment: //Add this logic in Controller to move completed list to last index
public static void Move(List<string> list,int newIndex,int oldIndex)
{
var item = list[oldIndex];
list.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--; 
list.Insert(newIndex, item);
}

Comment: The above logic is helpful or not to move the completed M2I List in our case to last index of list

Comment: I have updated my answer with front end code. Please check the pregress bar about job3.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Front-end gif picture first.

[image]

And the code here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>css3 dynamic</title>
</head>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .box{
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }
    .skill {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .skill li {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .skill li .expand-box{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #092c99;
        position: relative;
    }
    .skill li em:first-child {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        left: 0;
    }
    .skill li em:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        right: 0;
    }
    .expand {
        height: 13px;
        margin: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: #2187e7;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 198, 255, 0.4);
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <ul class="skill" id="chart"></ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        let listdata = [
        {"data1":"Job 1","data2":54},
        {"data1":"Job 2","data2":3},
        {"data1":"Job 3","data2":12},
        {"data1":"Job 4","data2":65},
        {"data1":"Job 5","data2":3}
        ];

        const compareData2 = (arrayItemA, arrayItemB) => {
            if (arrayItemA.data2 < arrayItemB.data2) {
                return 1
            }
            if (arrayItemA.data2 > arrayItemB.data2) {
                return -1
            }
            return 0
        }

        const objectComparisonCallback = (arrayItemA, arrayItemB) => {
            // first sort by data2
            return compareData2(arrayItemA, arrayItemB)
        }
        listdata.sort(objectComparisonCallback)

        loadData(listdata);

        
        var job3 = setInterval(function(){
            //find Job3
            const index = listdata.findIndex(object => {
                return object.data1 === "Job 3";
            }); // ️ 1

            if (index !== -1) {
                if(listdata[index].data2< 100){
                    listdata[index].data2 += 1;
                    $('#chart').empty();
                    listdata.sort(objectComparisonCallback);
                    loadData(listdata);
                    //clear all the css style about the .animations2
                    $(".animations"+index).css("width",listdata[index].data2+"%")
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Job 3 COMPLETED!");
                    clearInterval(job3);
                }
            }
        }, 100);
        
    })

    function loadData(listdata){
        
        let _html = '';
        let len = listdata.length;
        if(len > 0){
            for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
                _html += '<li>';
                _html += '<em>'+listdata[i]['data1']+'</em>';
                _html += '<div class="expand-box"><span class="expand animations'+i+'"></span></div>';
                _html += '<em>'+listdata[i]['data2']+'%</em>';
                _html += '</li>';

                let newStyle=document.styleSheets[0];
                
                newStyle.insertRule(
                    ".animations"+i+" { " +
                    "width: "+listdata[i]['data2']+"%;" +
                    "-moz-animation:animations"+i+" 0s ease-out;" +
                    "-webkit-animation:animations"+i+" 0s ease-out;" +
                    "}", 0);
                newStyle.insertRule(
                    "@keyframes animations"+i+"{ " +
                    "0% { width: 0; } " +
                    "100% { width:"+listdata[i]['data2']+" % }" +
                    "}",0);
                $('#chart').html(_html);
            }
        }else{
            $('#chart').html('No Data');
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should learn [the signalr in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

The use of Signalr can carry out real-time communication very well, and the background task execution process can be sent to the front-end page through websocket in real time. You can implement the sorting of the front-end pages according to your needs.

Here is a complete sample code, you can refer to the blog to realize your needs.

[Communicate the status of a background job with SignalR](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/)

Comment: Hi  @Jason Pan can you please help me to implement sorting at the front end. Only sorting is left I have added Move method in the comment

Comment: @Rishab Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: Hi @Jason pan Thanks for the efforts. But your are interpreting the question in different ways. Question is as simple as we need to sort list on view.there is no signalr concept is involved.

Comment: @Rishab I have provided enough sample code for you. Could you read the link and test by yourself?